# How can I change the MySQL root password in DDEV?

Tags: ddev

Long story short I'm wanting to change the root mysql user password?

Looking at the config in `.ddev` it looks pretty baked in (for example in `.ddev/.global_commands/host/sequelace` the root user name and password are hard coded).

I can go the long way around and do something like https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html, but wanted to check first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you have full control of the database.

In DDEV the default root password is "root", so if that's good enough for you you don't have to change it.

But with MySQL or MariaDB, you would just change it using

```
ddev mysql -u root
```

and change the password for `root@%` and `root@localhost`:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somenewpassword';
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somenewpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The built-in default password will no longer work of course.

DDEV just uses a standard mysql/mariadb server.

If you're using postgresql the procedure would be slightly different but the same idea with `ddev psql`.

For basics of database management see https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/basics/database_management/

Comment: Hi @rfay, thanks for that!

Basically I'm migrating some docker-compose config over to DDEV and a lot of the commands assume no root user password, not ideal.

Working around this for now!

Comment: I'm sure you already know that the `db` user is the normal user to use. Password is `db`, Host is `db`, Database is `db`.

Comment: Yeah, this is the first time I've ever needed to do anything with the root user to be fair.

Chucked you $20 on GitHub, I've been using DDEV for years now and you've always been dead helpful when I've had questions! Keep up the good work

Comment: Thanks so much! That helps the community several different ways.